# Create a program to update a label that displays the current percent of students that passed the exam

Tags: vb.net

I need to create a program for school. The requirements are: Design a program that has five buttons, one for each grade. Each time you press a button it increments that grade by one.  At the same time it updates a label that displays the current percent of students that passed the exam (grade higher than F). 
We've been working with counters and if...else statements/case...select statements.

This is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Static intCounterA As Integer = 0
    Static intCounterB As Integer = 0
    Static intCounterC As Integer = 0
    Static intCounterD As Integer = 0
    Static intCounterF As Integer = 0
    Static intCounterTotal As Integer = 0

    Dim dblTotal As Double


    dblTotal = intCounterTotal

    Me.lblTotal.Text = dblTotal


End Sub

Private Sub btnA_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnA.Click
    Static intCounterA As Integer = 0
    intCounterA = intCounterA + 1
    Me.lblA.Text = intCounterA
End Sub

Private Sub btnB_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnB.Click
    Static intCounterB As Integer = 0
    intCounterB = intCounterB + 1
    Me.lblB.Text = intCounterB
End Sub

Private Sub btnC_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnC.Click
    Static intCounterC As Integer = 0
    intCounterC = intCounterC + 1
    Me.lblC.Text = intCounterC
End Sub

Private Sub btnD_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnD.Click
    Static intCounterD As Integer = 0
    intCounterD = intCounterD + 1
    Me.lblD.Text = intCounterD
End Sub

Private Sub btnF_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnF.Click
    Static intCounterF As Integer = 0
    intCounterF = intCounterF + 1
    Me.lblF.Text = intCounterF
End Sub
```

I just need the lblTotal to display the percentage of students who are passing, and what I have is only returning NaN. Any help?

Comment: You need to debug your code, i.e. set a breakpoint at the start and then step through it line by line, evaluating all your variables and other relevant expressions at each step. As soon as you find behaviour that you don't expect, you've found an issue. Even if you can't fix it yourself, at least you can provide us with all the relevant information. `NaN` means "not a number" so you are performing an invalid mathematical operation somewhere. It should be obvious where when you debug. That said, it should be obvious if you simply read the code critically.

Comment: Hmm what's `0/0`? Is it a number? To clarify, you're initially setting everything to 0 and your operation is zero divided by zero which is `NaN`. Try updating the label value when you click the buttons. Your `intCounterTotal` should be a function that your button events can call so that you can update it in one place and simply call the function from each event.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, try something like this.

I would recommend shortening variable names as it makes the code tedious to write.

It's easier to write using a collection or array whenever you start needing multiple variables to interact with each other, but I know you're still learning.

In the `UpdateTotals` sub I added 2 variables that aren't really needed just to make the code easier to read.

For some reason, you declared your variables as static in the `Form1_Load` scope which seems wrong.

Make them global if you want to use them this way.

Also, don't redefine them in your button click events...

**Edit:** The code built and working:

[image: Working]

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim intCounterA As Integer = 0
    Dim intCounterB As Integer = 0
    Dim intCounterC As Integer = 0
    Dim intCounterD As Integer = 0
    Dim intCounterF As Integer = 0
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.lblA.Text = intCounterA
        Me.lblB.Text = intCounterB
        Me.lblC.Text = intCounterC
        Me.lblD.Text = intCounterD
        Me.lblF.Text = intCounterF
    End Sub
    Private Sub UpdateTotal()
        Dim n, d
        n = (intCounterA + intCounterB + intCounterC + intCounterD + intCounterF) - intCounterF
        d = intCounterA + intCounterB + intCounterC + intCounterD + intCounterF
        Me.lblTotal.Text = Math.Round(((n / d) * 100), 2) & "%" 'Display as percentage - round to 2 decimals
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnA_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnA.Click
        intCounterA = intCounterA + 1
        Me.lblA.Text = intCounterA
        UpdateTotal()
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnB_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnB.Click
        intCounterB = intCounterB + 1
        Me.lblB.Text = intCounterB
        UpdateTotal()
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnC_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnC.Click
        intCounterC = intCounterC + 1
        Me.lblC.Text = intCounterC
        UpdateTotal()
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnD_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnD.Click
        intCounterD = intCounterD + 1
        Me.lblD.Text = intCounterD
        UpdateTotal()
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnF_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnF.Click
        intCounterF = intCounterF + 1
        Me.lblF.Text = intCounterF
        UpdateTotal()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What does the line "UpdateTotal()" actually do?

Comment: It calls the subroutine `UpdateTotal()`. Basically, all the code in `Private Sub UpdateTotal` runs when we type `UpdateTotal()` anywhere in our code.

Comment: If you want to get rid of the `NaN` altogether, you can add some code in `UpdateTotal` to make sure that `d <> 0` ... so, for example, you could add `If d = 0 Then Me.lblTotal.Text = "" Exit Sub End If` (4 lines)